# Uncaught ReferenceError: date is not defined

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

Hey I'm trying to create a heartbeat that will tell me when a customer is done with a session.

My controller looks like this:

```
def update
  @customer = Customer.find(params[:id])
  @room = Room.find(params[:room_id])
  @customer.charge(@room)
  @customer.update_attribute(finished_at: DateTime.now)
  session[:customer_id] = nil

  respond_to do |format|
    format.js
    format.htmt { redirect_to root_url }
  end
end
```

now in my show.html.erb file I have this:

```
setInterval(function(){
  $.post("/customers/<%= current_customer.id %>", {finished_at: date.now()}, function(){});
}, 5000);
```

now when I check my console the error I get is:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: date is not defined
```

There might be a couple of mistakes here, anybody knows whats up?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`date` is not the valid syntax.

Use `Date` not `date`, note the uppercase `D`

```
Date.now()
```

[**Docs**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date)

Comment: Perfect, now I get
POST http://localhost:3000/customers/53 404 (Not Found) any ideas on how to fix this?